# Recommend a Java Graphics API for this application idea

Tags: java, api, diagnostics, fsm, circuit

I want to make a tool for creating [FSM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) control circuit simulations. NB! not the ALU part.

Can anyone recommend a good Java API with as much functionality already available as possible? Itll basically be something like a graphical modelling language editor.

The user should be able to make and run stuff like this:[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of Java libraries out there for visualizing graphs. Some that I hear mentioned a lot include:

1. [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/)
2. [jGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/)
3. [GraphVis](http://www.graphviz.org/) and [Grappa](http://www2.research.att.com/~john/Grappa/)

The following blog has a pretty extensive list of options with commentary and screenshots: http://s6ai.livejournal.com/33969.html

Comment: just what i was looking for. cheers